# how to skip some rows in a multiple load with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I load more than 1000 files using pandas, but before that, I have to take of the first 4 lines in each file. How a can do it? I try usin skip but doesn´t work in this code below

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
dataframes = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in filesnames]
dataframes
```

Output:

```
[          Relatório Meteorológico da Estação: Guaratiba
 0     Dados normalizados para o Horário Brasileiro d...
 1     Dia         Hora      HBV   Chuva  DirVento  V...
 2                                          (graus)  ...
 3     01/03/2013  00:00:00          0.0         -   ...
 4     01/03/2013  00:15:00          0.0         -   ...
 5     01/03/2013  00:30:00          0.0         -   ...
 6     01/03/2013  00:45:00          0.0         -   ...
 7     01/03/2013  01:00:00          0.0         -   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To skip the first 3 rows, you can use the skip_rows argument of read_csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, skip_rows=3)
```

You can keep all the headers by doing:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, skip_rows=1) # Skip the first row, use second row as headers
df.drop(df.head(1).index, inplace=True) # Drop the first row of the dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have one more question, I need to convert all the title of txt as a first collumn in a data frame, How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following works:

```
dataframes = [pd.read_csv(f,skiprows=4) for f in filesnames]
```

Comment: You welcome .. Please mark the answer as Accepted & Up vote it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have one more question, I need to convert all  the title of txt as a first collumn in a data frame,  How can I do it?

Comment: Your question isn't clear .. can you elaborate it ... or post it as separate question with example ..

Comment: The fisrt line of my files have the name of place, i need to convert this information in a column in my data frame.

Answer (score 0):

it didn't work

I need to put the first information in a column (the first line dosen´t have index), the second line (index 0) will be remove, and de index 1 will be de header.

[          Relatório Meteorológico da Estação: Guaratiba
 0     Dados normalizados para o Horário Brasileiro d...
 1     Dia         Hora      HBV   Chuva  DirVento  V...
 2                                          (graus)  ...